# Troubles making a counter count from 1 to 12

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

I can't manage to figure out how to wire the schematic in order to make it count from 1 to 12 instead of having it count from 0 to 12 like i have it right now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you spilled some wires on the schematic you tried to draw. Perhaps if you group it into functional blocks, you could hold more in your mind at once and see the solution much more easily.

Comment: Yeah really... don't be afraid to put the logic in another area and use named signals or something.

Comment: Why not make it count from 0 to 11 and add 1 to the final number?

Answer (score 2):

You are using your counters entirely wrong. Do not derive a logic signal to drive a clock. Never, never, never. Instead, run the clock to all counters and then derive logic as follows

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMcGdC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Note that I have not bothered to deal with possible false states on power-up. That is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Could you expand on the rationale of not deriving a clock from logic?